# Opportunity is visible in reports

Tags: opportunity, visibility, accountshare

**Premise:** As per the business requirement all internal users **should see** all the **accounts**, but they should **NOT** be able to see all the **opportunities**. The only opportunities they should be able to see is their own. Both Account and Opportunity are set as private in the sharing settings. At account there's a rule for sharing all the accounts with all the internal users. At UI level everything is ok but in report level all unwanted opportunity are visible.

**Note:** Query on OpportunityShare suggests that opportunity is visible due to impllicit sharing. Also, settings related to Account team and Opportunity team members are verified.

**Question:** Is there any way by which I can restrict this implicitSharing of opportunity at report level? (Note: I do not want to put 'My Opportunity' filter at the report level, as the all the opportunity for which he/she should really have the access even though he/she is not the owner, should be visible).

Comment: Hi there, I think it would be good to get some clarity on what your actual requirement is. You have said in your premise that your users should only be able to see their own opportunities, but in your question you've said that you can't filter my My Opportunities. Those statements appear to be a contradiction, so could you please [edit] your question to help make this clearer?